# set attribute disabled with angular ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have and object in my main.ts which may be initialized. In the case it is I have to disable a textarea in the html. I have tried this:

```
ng-attr-disabled="!myObj";
ng-attr-disabled="{myObj!= null}";
```

same with directly `ng-disabled`.

I have also tried this: `[disabled]="{'disabled':myObj!=null}"`

but nothing of this have worked unfortunately.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="message" id="txtMessage" formControlName="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

TS:

```
  myObj;
  constructor(...) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('message') && localStorage.getItem('message') != null){
      this.myObj = localStorage.getItem('message');
    }
  }
```

Any idea of what can I try?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
[attr.disabled]="!myObj"
```

Comment: worked, but it sets `disabled="true"` and `disabled="false"` in case myObj exists, is it possible to just set disabled to true but not  disable to false?

Comment: i don't know what you mean may you please explain more. you can use every variable you want instead of `!myObj` and handle it's value in your ts file.

Comment: It was just because I used the same with a select / option to make one of the options to be selected by default. I tried something like: `[attr.selected]="myObj.option == 'someString' "` but it output `selected="true"` or `selected="false"`. `selected="false"` is not recognized by html5 so it did't work as I wanted. Anyway I solved it by using `ng-model="myObj.option"` inside the select tag and it automatically selects the option that matches with the object value given.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate boolean variable for this:

```
isDisabled = false;
constructor(...) {
  if(localStorage.getItem('message') && localStorage.getItem('message') != null){
    this.myObj = localStorage.getItem('message');
    this.isDisabled = true;
  }
}
...
...
<textarea [disabled]="isDisabled" name="message" id="txtMessage" formControlName="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```